# I reside in Denmark with my Danish wife. My work is seasonal. How long can I work in another EU country per year?

Tags: freelance

I am an a scientific artist and my work so far is quite seasonal. I am a non EU citizen (Australian). I am on a family re-unification visa and I pay Danish tax. Can I work in another EU country for the 'off season'/ Summer?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go for less than three months somewhere else in the Schengen area, you don't necessarily need a work *visa* or residence permit but, unless your wife moves to that other EU country with you, you do need some sort of *authorisation* to work.

Additionally, if you live in Denmark since more than 5 years, you might be considered a [long-term EU resident](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=URISERV:l23034) and should be allowed to reside for more than three months elsewhere in the EU somewhat more easily. But you don't have an automatic right to work in another country – either short-term or long-term – and would still need to apply for a permit/authorisation as applicable.

So, these subtle distinctions aside, your status in Denmark does not fundamentally change your situation with respect to other EU countries. There is no easy solution for your problem, you need to get the local bureaucracy to issue some sort of permit before you can work in another country, even short-term.

On the other hand, if you are selling your services (not sure that's a phrase you would use of course!) under the guise of a company/as a self-employed person instead of seeking an employment contract, other rules might apply, I am not entirely sure.

Comment: I also have my own company. Does this help me in working abroad in any way. Are there any benefits of having my own company, with regards to the limits that are still in place abroad?

Comment: @TomLock It could be but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You may work from Denmark (remotely). Otherwise you would need work visa in the coutry where your next assignment would be located. Being spouse of EU citizen entitles you to work permit for only one country; the one you reside in.

Comment: Technically, the OP most likely isn't considered the spouse of an EU citizen, as he is probably residing in Denmark under Danish rules. It's only outside your spouse's country of origin that EU freedom of movement rules apply (with some caveat like the ‘Surinder Singh route‘).